# Do we have a simulation software for switching and routing practice? 

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a simulation software for switching and routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best choice is probably [Cisco's 'Packet Tracer'](http://www.packettracernetwork.com/). Packet Tracer 5.2 is the lastest and is available in .DEB format on their site (login required...
<sub>I have found other locations where to download the deb from but I do not want to give out untrusted sources. If you need it from one of these sources: google ;)</sub>).

```
Packet Tracer is a powerful network simulator that can be utilized in 
training for CCNATM and CCNPTM certification exam by allowing students 
to create networks with an almost unlimited number of devices and to
 experience troubleshooting without having to buy real CiscoTM routers
 or switches.
```

[How to](http://www.ubuntuka.com/run-cisco-packet-tracer-in-ubuntu/) install it in Ubuntu (should work in 11.04 too)

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Network Simulator (`ns2`) in Ubuntu by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ns2
```

Or click here:

[image: Install via the software center]